Unity - My MS 4.8 DLL works however MS ADOMDNet client fails with 'Method not implemented'
(I posted this on the Unity Android forum and no replies yet so I thought I'd also add here).
I've dug around the web a lot and tried various things.
I have written my own C# DLL to communicate with remote OLAP cubes. This is called CubeMDX and my core code works with Unity. This in turn calls the official Microsoft DLL Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient (which does the hard work) which works on Windows however my app (an AR app but the AR bit is not relevant here) is an Android app.
I note that in the Player Settings there is MS .Net Core 2.1 or .Net framework so I set this to .Net Framework. I also set Internet to Require (as comms with a cube is XMLA over http).

I tried a 'Depedency Walker' exe to look at the libraries that this DLL seems to need, and it did appear to be tons. I did note that it needs mscoree.dll, which I found and tried to add as an asset, didn't work, and then I tried creating an rsp file (as per this page https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileAssemblies.html) and that didn't work.
My CubeMDX code works, and I get an object created for ADoMDConnection, however as soon as my code tries to call a method on the Connection object I get an error.

Here's an example method in my CubeMDX with tick and cross for what works and then what fails:

So .Open(), or any other method, fails whereas the CubeConn is instantiated (and connectionString is valid and cube is running.
In Unity, I get an exception returned, with my message from above, "An error occurred retrieving measures: " and the error is:

An error occurred retrieving measures: The method or operation is not
implemented. UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
TreeViewManager:LoadFields () (at
Assets/Scripts/TreeViewManager.cs:30) TreeViewManager:Start () (at
Assets/Scripts/TreeViewManager.cs:15)

I am guessing that 'The method or operation is not implemented' is a fairly generic message shown when a forward dependency or lib is not found at a lower level (on Windows it finds what it needs however this is Android when running). I'd also guess that the Player settings only allowing ARM7 will also mean it will not work.
So my question for experienced/pro Unity people, as I am still learning Unity however I've been developing software for media companies and investment banks since late 90s so you can be very technical in replies, is - is there a way to discover what else I need to package here to get this working? Or would I be banging my head against a wall :) and do I need to take my C# and port it to Java and try OLAP comms that way (I know Java since the 90s too) and then run it as an AndroidObject instead (I noted this approach as I dug around)?
Many thanks
Mr Leigh Tilley
https://tilleytech.com
